# More PHP files are detected as virus

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, virus

Server scanner were found more files under drupal sites folder. Screenshot below.

This is linux  [ ubuntu ] server with drupal 7.x

Scanned Results is those files are really virus.

1. sites/default/files/jss.php.suspected   php.malware.empty_concatenation.001
2. sites/default/files/simple.php5 php.backdoor.xhell.001.01
3. sites/default/files/pas.php.suspected   php.backdoor.pas_webshell.004
4. sites/default/files/accesson.php.suspected  php.phishing.paypal.013.04
5. sites/default/files/search.php  php.malware.generic.020.001
6. sites/default/files/content-post.php.suspected  php.backdoor.xhell.001.01

Comment: Did you verify content of those file ? verify rights on this file , it must not be writable

Comment: Yes, and most of the files are editable but it is not belonging to Drupal. I have deleted all of them. Thanks for the involvement ..

Comment: What is the question ?  
If you want to know how to resolve you should check all your project files if it's impacted also on sites/default/files and deleted manually and update you drupal core to drupal 7.67 because the version 7.58 and less was PHP Object Injection Vulnerability